# How to install/update libnl-1.0pre8 (or later)

Tags: wireless, internet, libraries, hostapd

I was trying to share my laptop's internet over wireless to use as wi-fi in my android phone. After googling for some time I am now stuck here:

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd

the instruction says: "you need to install/update libnl-1.0pre8 (or later)" for a certain error I am getting. But I am unable to do so. I downloaded the package all right, but executing the makefile of that package is giving me errors.
Is there another way to install/update this application? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `libnl-dev` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked!!! 1 more thing though. If I ever wanted to install/update any library, is there any way to know which package it is contained in? This one for example, I didn't find it anywhere on googling. Can't I search apt-get repository or something?

Comment: Yes, you can. The command is `apt-cache search <package_name>`. However, it would result in a lot of packages. In this case, you can try `apt-cache search libnl`.